# how to create custom auto increment for string field in laravel

Tags: laravel

i need to save a custom auto increment string when a new product is created. What is the best way to achieve this in laravel

this is the outcome that i want

```
   id     sku        product_name
    1     'sku-001'    milk
    2     'sku-002'    cerelac
    2     'sku-003'    milo
```

this is my current code

```
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('sku');
        $table->string('name')->unique();

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use model event's. Below you have the boot function in which you would put into your model. After that you would have access to various of event's like creating, created, updating, updated .. so on and so for. We are interested in created, as it is triggered after your model is saved.

The static method receives a function that has as parameter an instance of the model that was just saved so you can access the id and concatenate with the string you want.

```
/**
 * Enables us to hook into model event's
 *
 * @return void 
 */
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::created(function($product) {
        $product->sku .= 'sku-' . $product->id;
        $product->save();
    });
}
```

Comment: how to ensures the id is preceeded by '00' without hardcoding it to 'sku-00'

Comment: thanks @nullisnotundefined i used switch case to switch between single digits and double.

Answer (score 1):

Yes sure, but you have to generate it in your own. like this one

```
$id = "sku-000";
echo ++$id; // sku-001
echo "<br>";
echo ++$id; // sku-002
```

Remember that you to have fetch first the last inserted Id and get the sku of this then do the increment process. like this one

```
$last_id = Product::orderBy('sku', 'desc')->first()->sku;
$last_id = $last_id++;

Product::create(['sku' => $last_id, 'name' => 'test product']);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Method:**

```
$latestorder = Order::where('status','processing')->latest('created_at')->first();

if($latestorder->exists()) {
    $total = $latestorder->total_count+1;
} else {
    $total = 1;
}

$order->status = 'processing';
$order->total_count = $total;
```